Vscode autocomplete does not show newer feactures methods in .js our .ts files
My Vscode autocomplete isn't shown new methods like str.at() (ES2022) or str.replaceAll() (ES2021). And this does not happen only with strings, but with any other new feature like ar.findLast() (ES2023), etc... And this is happening with both .js and .ts files.
All is up to date: my node, my vscode and I have extensions like: IntelliCode, JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly and ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets installed... (among others)
This is my settings.json
...
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": { "javascript": "jsx" },
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "typescript": "typescriptreact",
        "ejs": "html",
        "django-html": "html"
},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,   
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",     
"javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
"javascript.suggest.autoImports": true,
"javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": true,
"javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
    
"typescript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
"typescript.suggestionActions.enabled": true,
"typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
"typescript.suggest.autoImports": true,
"typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
    
"code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
//"code-runner.runInTerminal": true, //only 2 Python
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.executorMap": {
            "javascript": "node",
            "typescript": "npx ts-node --files", //2 local install
            //"typescript": "ts-node --files", //2 global install
    
            "python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && venv\\Scripts\\python.exe -u", //code-runner exec python of venv
            "bat": "cmd /c"


 },
 ...

I already try chatGPT but it can not help me.
Someone know why they aren't shown? And how I fix it?
Thanks

Well, I had the same problem while making one of my projects - I solved that I created the jsconfig.json directly to workspace.
Code looks like this:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
        "target": "ES2023", //this value is required to show this
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}

If you don't understand where create the file, you can see the file tree below, as an example
Workspace
├── README.md
├── jsconfig.js <<<
└── .gitignore


Okay, I dug it deeper, and if you want to change the target to all workspaces, just go to the settings and search for "target".
Setting id: js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.target
Code to insert this to settings.json:
...
"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.target": "ES2022"
...


Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. GPT Chat has suggested this too, but I've tried it in the settings.json of VSCode itself. Now I tried it, like you said, in the settings.json in the workspace, but it still doesn't work either.
Is this a bug in VSCode? Because this feature isn't that recent, it should be showing up.

I think you could understood it wrong. You have to put this code into the jsconfig.json file, not settings.json.  I also edited a minute ago the post, which you can see the information about changing the target to whole VSC

Wow! Really thanks. This works nicely. I just add this line: "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.target": "ESNext" to my settings.json, and now all the newest methods is being shown. Thanks!
Note - add ESNext instead ES2022 and it will work to latest versions too.
thanks again :)
